# Hackerrank, challenges problem. Why does the query return unique output of count (challenges)?

Tags: sql, having

Here is the link for the problem: [Hackerrannk-challenges](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/challenges/problem?isFullScreen=true)

One of the solution:

```
SELECT 
    c.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(c.challenge_id) AS cnt 
FROM 
    Hackers AS h 
JOIN 
    Challenges AS c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY 
    c.hacker_id, h.name 
HAVING 
    cnt = (SELECT COUNT(c1.challenge_id) 
           FROM Challenges AS c1 
           GROUP BY c1.hacker_id 
           ORDER BY count(*) DESC
           LIMIT 1)
    OR cnt NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(c2.challenge_id) 
                   FROM Challenges AS c2 
                   GROUP BY c2.hacker_id 
                   HAVING c2.hacker_id <> c.hacker_id)
ORDER BY 
    cnt DESC, c.hacker_id;
```

I can not understand why this part returns unique outputs:

```
cnt NOT IN (SELECT count(c2.challenge_id) 
            FROM Challenges AS c2 
            GROUP BY c2.hacker_id 
            HAVING c2.hacker_id <> c.hacker_id)
```

I'm especially interested how `HAVING c2.hacker_id <> c.hacker_id` works.

Comment: Hi - 1) questions on this forum need to be self-contained so please don’t link to the actual requirements, add them to your question as editable text 2) show sample data for your tables, the result you are trying to achieve and the result you are actually getting (all as editable text)

Comment: That part doesn't *return* anything and it isn't concerned with uniqueness. Most people would write that with `where` rather than `having` btw. The subquery evaluates to a list of all challenge counts except the hacker id from the outer query. In other words, did somebody else do the same number?